# bootstrap select-picker style z-index not working

Tags: html, css, angularjs

When I use bootstrap select-picker in table responsive,select-picker is cover and it appear scroll bar. I use z-index but not working.
[image]
I want not show scroll bar, content not cover.
Thanks so much!

Comment: Can you show us some code related to this ?

Comment: I take a photo: https://gyazo.com/19c0bce9c493f74b1b8c9291c5628756
https://gyazo.com/cee21861090c6bdebcd847d5013ee3c3